# The line between the midpoints of two arcs on a circumscribed circle of a triangle in tangent to the inscribed circle of that triangle

Tags: geometry

I need to prove, that the line is tangent to the circle. I also attached my approach. I'm working on this problem for a few hours, I had a few approaches, but all of them were wrong.  (This problem is from the Polish *XI Olimpiada Matematyczna Gimnazjalistów* (question 4 from [this document](http://www.omg.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/1etap15.pdf). The submission deadline of 12 October 2015 has passed.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arc $AB$ is equal to arc $XY$: if $O$ is the center of the outer circle, then $\angle AOB=120^\circ$ (double of $60^\circ$) and $240^\circ =\angle AOC+\angle BOC = 2\angle COX + 2\angle COY = 2\angle XOY$. So chords $AB$ and $XY$ are equal.

The center $W$ of the inner circle belongs to the bisectors of $\angle CAB$ and $\angle ABC$, that is it belongs to $AX$ and $BY$. But it is then easy to prove that triangles $AWB$ and $YWX$ are equal, from which the claim follows.

Comment: thank you very much for the proof. I understand almost everything apart from this claim:
`The center W of the inner circle belongs to the bisectors of ∠CAB and ∠ABC, that is it belongs to AX and BY`
Why is that? I mean why bisectors ∠CAB and ∠ABC belong to AX and BY?

Comment: If $X$ is the midpoint of arc $BC$, then by definition $\angle BOX=\angle COX$. But then also $\angle BAX=\angle CAX$, so that $AX$ is the bisector of $\angle BAC$. The same goes for $Y$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have one more question - having shown, that AWB and YWX are equal, how can I now prove, that XY is tangent to the inscribed circle?

Comment: Two equal triangles also have equal heights. So the distance of side $XY$ from $W$ is equal to the distance of side $AB$ from $W$, but that is precisely the radius of inner triangle.